# Needing some tips on toning up

Tags: strength, toning

I have lost a good amount of weight, but now it is time to tone up and get ready for swim suit season.Not only toning up but i need to build some strength as well. What kind of exercises can help me with toning up but also help me build up some strength?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll get to the answer quickly - lift weights!  Find a good gym, a good strength coach/personal trainer or do a lot of research on a weight lifting program that will not only get you strong, but keep you lean and get you in the shape you want.  Here's a great resource: www.bodybuilding.com - take a look around.  If you can't afford a gym or personal trainer get ready to do a lot of research - read anything from Dan John or Jim Wendler.  Want more advice? let me know - good luck!!!

Comment: Thank you very much! this is very helpful, i had some health issues long story short it made me lose a lot of weight in a short amount of time about 30 to 40 pounds within 3 1/2 months so i am not trying to lose anymore weight. My main goal now is too tone up and to build strength

Comment: @Jessica - You took the biggest step, know it's more tough work to get your plan together and follow it.  I would start by learning all the basic lifts (deadlift, squat, bench, press) and practicing them for 2-3 weeks (you'll never stop learning how to improve on them).  During that time look into the various weight lifting plans (5x5 starting strenght, madcow, 5/3/1) - pick one- and stick with it for 2-3 month min....never give up, never look back and never put yourself in position where you'll get hurt and not be able to train the next day.  let us know how it goes - GOOD LUCK

Comment: Thank you very much! this information is very helpful and this time around i have decided to get a personal trainer not only support but for tips and advice